# What is number 15 in date command?

Tags: date

I need to know what does the number 15 mean here and where it comes from.
I searched enough for it so I appreciate a little help:

```
for i in {1..12} ; do
   mkdir $(LC_TIME=C date +%B -d "${i}/15")
done
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it has any significance apart from being a day that is guaranteed to occur in any month (you could use any number from 1 up to and including 28)

Comment: That's right thanks ....

Comment: But not 3 to 13. They did not appear in September 1752.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the day.

```
test@com:~/test$ for i in {1..12} ; do echo $(LC_TIME=C date +%B -d "${i}/29"); done
January
date: invalid date ‘2/29’

March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

Comment: Thanks now i understand ......